# Finding the root directory of a dependency in NPM

Tags: node.js

Let's say I have installed `awesome-package` inside `my-app`, and let's say the structure looks like:

```
my-app/
  node_modules/
    awesome-package/
      node_modules/
        another-package/
          static/
            index.js
      dist/
        index.js
  dist/
    index.js
```

Inside `my-app/index.js` I do `require('awesome-package')`. Now I want to get the root directory of `awesome-package`, so I can basically `fs.readFileSync` something from `another-package`

How can I get the root directory of a script?

Comment: @ Kousha The answer you accepted doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [require.resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options) can be used to achieve that. It will give you the full path to the module. Getting the root directory from that should be easy.

```js
const path = require('path');
let loc = require.resolve('awesome-package');

// most likely something like the following depends on the package
// /path/to/my-app/node_modules/awesome-package/static/index.js
console.log(loc);

// something like the following will give you the root directory
// of the package
console.log(path.join(
  loc.substring(0,a.lastIndexOf('node_modules')),
  'node_modules',
  'awesome-package'
));
```

Comment: That doesn't work if `awesome-package` doesn't define `package.json#main` / `package.json#exports["."]`.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer doesn't work on esm package.
Accepted answer return cjs path.

Answer for esm path

```
const fullPath = await import.meta.resolve("package_name");
console.log(fullPath);
```

need to add flag: `--experimental-import-meta-resolve`

Comment: That doesn't work if awesome-package doesn't define package.json#main / package.json#exports["."]

Comment: @brillout find anyone packages who doesn't define main or exports key in package.json